How to speed up the simulation in the case of massive data transmission？
When I run a lot of actors on every host to achieve massive data transmission, it costs more the six hours on 6000000 cores.
Each actor need to create streams and send to a specified host or actor (put_async and get) and all of them compete for real computing resources (single core).
How can I make the most of real computing resources (physical multi-core)?
I noticed a configuration option:contexts/nthreads. Can it help me? But I met a problem in my last question.question

6 hours for 6M cores looks like a many-thousands-speedup to me, isn't it? Of course it depends on the elapsed time within the simulator at the end of that experiment, but I suspect that the overall speedup remains good. It would be good to be even faster but that's already not that bad, I'd say.
To speed things further, you can try to reduce a bit the timing resolutions or increase the max concurrency limit. It could help a bit but I don't expect massive improvement either. Another idea could be to change the optimization level to full, since the default 'lazy' value is not adapted to a highly contention scenario such as yours.
Please don't forget to report how these parameters improve your situation, possibly on smaller simulations.
